# The error: System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#

The code looks as following:

```
public static class ResLocator
{
    public static string Resolve(Type assemblyObjectType, string resourceName)
    {
        MethodInfo resourceLocatorMethod = typeof(System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader).GetMethod(
                "GetWebResourceUrlInternal", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null,
                CallingConventions.Any, new[] { typeof(Assembly), typeof(string), typeof(bool), typeof(bool), typeof(ScriptManager) }, null);

        string url = string.Format("/{0}", resourceLocatorMethod.Invoke(
            null,
            new object[] { Assembly.GetAssembly(assemblyObjectType), resourceName, false })
        );

        return url;
    }
}
```

The error: System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException was unhandled by user code, comes up on Invoke.

I'm not sure what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you're relying on an internal implementation detail to start with? Well it sounds like you're calling the method with the wrong number of arguments. Where is that method declared? (As in, do you have a link to the source?)

Comment: Probably [this one](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Handlers/AssemblyResourceLoader.cs,c3179e7329c55e12), @JonSkeet.

Comment: Well that would make sense of the error, given that the OP is providing 3 arguments and the method has 5 parameters.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, you're specifying the types of the parameters for the method you're looking for:

```
new[] { typeof(Assembly), typeof(string), typeof(bool), typeof(bool), typeof(ScriptManager) }
```

Here, you're specifying the argument values to correspond to those parameters:

```
new object[] { Assembly.GetAssembly(assemblyObjectType), resourceName, false })
```

So you've provided 3 arguments, but there are 5 parameters. That's not going to work. The exception even tells you what you're doing wrong, in terms of the invocation.

More importantly, invoking internal methods like this is a *really bad idea*. Sure, that exists now - but it could easily change in a future version of the library, at which point your code would break even if it were working now. If the author of the library had intended you to call it, they'd have made it public.

Reflection is important and has plenty of valid uses, particularly around testing your own code, but it's *not* a good idea to use it to effectively try to call code in other libraries which you're not meant to have access to.

Comment: It's ok, but I can't see another way to access embedded JavaScript file from external assembly in MVC application.

Comment: @tesicg: If it's embedded in the assembly, why not just use `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`?

Comment: Here's an example: http://coding.altervista.org/blog/2012/07/asp-net-mvc-caricare-un-file-javascript-embedded/

Comment: @tesicg: Just because someone else is doing it doesn't make it a good idea :) I don't know enough about what you're trying to do - or ASP.NET - to suggest much myself, but I'd be astonished if that were really the best approach available.